# How to install console for plugin development in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

Can't find answer for this issue: how to install console for plugin development on October CMS. There are some tips on their site:

https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands

but they are unclear for me (maybe because im new to this CMS).
Can someone write how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the October console interface (or actually it is Laravels Artisan) you have to install October via composer.

1. [Download and install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)
2. [Install October via Composer](https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands)

   `composer create-project october/october myoctober dev-master`
3. Use the command line commands for plugin development.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. But I have further questions: should I install composer  and october locally (e.g. on WampServer) or could I just load composer and october directly on website ? My goal is to write plugin for october.

Comment: @mac Development should always happen locally and production on server. So - install both on server and locally.